# Renaming a populated iMac Snow Leopard external HDD a possibility?

Tags: macos

I want to place my iMac Snow Leopard Users Folder on a separate external HDD. It is already populated with data in my Documents, Downloads etc., and Media Folders. My problem is I have already named the HDD using Disk Utility. Is it possible to rename the disk without having to erase the data it contains, Just the name?

Comment: If you feel like your question has been answered, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Select the drive (just like any other file/folder) and press enter, and rename it just like any other file/folder

Answer (score 1):

Renaming an external drive is as easy as right-clicking its name in the Finder sidebar and selecting the appropriate option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Select the drive in finder, press CMD + I (or right click and select Get Info), and you can change the name in the "Name & Extension" box about half way down.